# VHDL NxM -bit parallel block multiplier

Tags: vhdl

I am trying to create schematics for a NxM -bit parallel block multiplier using generic parameters to define the size of the multiplier, and generate statements to describe the internal structure. I am having some trouble with my sums and carries and I am not able to implement what I want to do in VHDL code.

Here is what I got so far:

**1-bit multiplier:**

```
library IEEE;  
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;  
use IEEE.std_logic_arith.all;  
use ieee.numeric_std.all;  
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity mult is  
 port (  
  a     :  in std_logic;  
  b     :  in std_logic;  
  Sin   :  in std_logic;        --sum-in  
  Cin   :  in std_logic;        --carry-in  
  Sout  :  out std_logic;       --sum-out  
  Cout  :  out std_logic        --carry-out  
);  
end mult;  

architecture mult of mult is  
  begin  

Sout <= '1' when a = '0' and b = '0' and Sin = '0' and Cin = '1' else
        '1' when a = '0' and b = '0' and Sin = '1' and Cin = '0' else
        '1' when a = '0' and b = '1' and Sin = '1' and Cin = '0' else
        '1' when a = '0' and b = '1' and Sin = '0' and Cin = '1' else
        '1' when a = '1' and b = '0' and Sin = '0' and Cin = '1' else
        '1' when a = '1' and b = '0' and Sin = '1' and Cin = '0' else
        '1' when a = '1' and b = '1' and Sin = '0' and Cin = '0' else
        '1' when a = '1' and b = '1' and Sin = '1' and Cin = '1' else
        '0';
Cout <= '1' when a = '0' and b = '0' and Sin = '1' and Cin = '1' else
        '1' when a = '0' and b = '1' and Sin = '1' and Cin = '1' else
        '1' when a = '1' and b = '0' and Sin = '1' and Cin = '1' else
        '1' when a = '1' and b = '1' and Sin = '0' and Cin = '1' else
        '1' when a = '1' and b = '1' and Sin = '1' and Cin = '0' else
        '1' when a = '1' and b = '1' and Sin = '1' and Cin = '1' else
        '0';

end mult;
```

**Used it as a component in an NxM multiplier:**

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.std_logic_arith.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity generic_mult is
        generic (bits: integer);
 port (
  a     :  in std_logic_vector(bits-1 downto 0);
  b     :  in std_logic_vector(bits-1 downto 0);
  answer:  out std_logic_vector(bits*2-1 downto 0)      --sum-out
  );
end entity generic_mult;

architecture behavioral of generic_mult is

 component mult is
  port (
    a    :  in std_logic;
    b    :  in std_logic;
    Sin  :  in std_logic;       --sum-in
    Cin  :  in std_logic;       --carry-in
    Sout :  out std_logic;      --sum-out
    Cout :  out std_logic       --carry-out
  );
 end component;

        type mem_word  is array (0 to bits) of std_logic_vector(bits downto 0);

        signal  carry_internal : mem_word;
        signal  sum_internal : mem_word;

  begin
    this_is_label: for N in 1 to bits generate --Im sorry, my labels are horrible :(
        this_is_label3: for M in 0 to bits-1 generate

            this_is_label2: mult
          port map (
            a => a(N-1),
            b => b(M),
            Cin => carry_internal(M)(N),
            Cout => carry_internal(M+1)(N),
            Sin => sum_internal(M)(N),
            Sout => sum_internal(M+1)(N-1)
        );
    end generate;
end generate;
    labellll: for N in 0 to bits-1 generate
        sum_internal(N+1)(N) <= carry_internal(N)(N);
    carry_internal(0) <= (others => '0');
    sum_internal(0)   <= (others => '0');

    answer(bits*2-1) <= carry_internal(bits)(bits);
    answer(bits downto 0) <= sum_internal(bits);
    end generate;
end behavioral;
```

**And a testbench for it:**

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity NM_mult_tb is
end NM_mult_tb;

architecture behavioral of NM_mult_tb is
    component generic_mult

        generic (bits: integer := 4);
 port (
  a     :  in std_logic_vector(bits-1 downto 0);
  b     :  in std_logic_vector(bits-1 downto 0);
  answer:  out std_logic_vector(bits*2-1 downto 0)      --sum-out
  );
    end component;
   --declaring inputs and initializing them
        signal a  :  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) :="0101";
        signal b  :  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) :="1010";
        signal Sin:  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) :="0000";
        signal Cin:  std_logic := '0';
   --declaring outputs and initializing them
        signal answer :  std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);  --sum-out
        signal correct:  std_logic;                     --carry-out

BEGIN
    -- Instantiating the Design Under Test (DUT)
   dut: generic_mult
        GENERIC MAP (4)
        PORT MAP (
          a => a,
          b => b,
         answer => answer
        );

   -- Stimulus process
    correct <= '1' when to_integer(unsigned(a))*to_integer(unsigned(b)) = 
to_integer(unsigned(answer)) else '0';
  stim_proc: process
   begin
        wait for 1 ns;
        a <= a + 1;
        if a = "0" then b <= b + 1; end if;
  end process;

END;
```

When I simulate it I see that there is something wrong with carry-ins and sum-ins and outs and my answer has undefined bits in it:

(I am not allowed to embedded images on this post before I have 10 reputation so here is a link to the image:) https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4ED9.png

[image]

If you have read my post this far, thank you very much for your attention. If someone could find the time to help me out with my problem I would be very grateful!

Sincerely,
A confused VHDL beginner

Comment: In your 1bit multiplier, Sout is always 1. Is this your intention?

Comment: @XeroSmith: You missed the "else '0';"

Comment: @TEMLIB unless I am missing the obvious, every possibility was exhausted before the else

Comment: @XeroSmith : 8 lines with " '1' when ...", and 4 inputs : I'd say Sout is set for half the possible combinations of the 4 inputs.

Comment: Oh yeah I see. I was about to say 4 inputs?? Then I scrolled across. My mistake, I'm viewing this on my phone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would work it. Code first:

**mult.vhd**

```
library ieee;  
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;  

entity mult is  
port ( a     :  in std_logic;  
       b     :  in std_logic;  
       pin   :  in std_logic;    -- product in  
       cin   :  in std_logic;    -- carry in  
       pout  :  out std_logic;   -- product out
       cout  :  out std_logic ); -- carry out  
end mult;  

architecture mult of mult is
begin  
    pout <= (a and b) xor cin xor pin;
    cout <= (a and b and cin) or (a and b and pin) or (cin and pin);
end mult;
```

**generic_mult.vhd**

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity generic_mult is
generic (N: integer; M: integer);
port ( a    :  in  std_logic_vector(N-1 downto 0);
       b    :  in  std_logic_vector(M-1 downto 0);
       prod :  out std_logic_vector(M+N-1 downto 0) );
end entity generic_mult;

architecture behavioral of generic_mult is

-- Components
component mult is
port (
    a    :  in std_logic;
    b    :  in std_logic;
    pin  :  in std_logic;
    cin  :  in std_logic;
    pout :  out std_logic;
    cout :  out std_logic );
end component;

-- Signals
type mem_word is array (0 to M-1) of std_logic_vector(N-1 downto 0);
signal cin  : mem_word;
signal cout : mem_word;
signal pin  : mem_word;
signal pout : mem_word;

begin

    m_loop: for i in 0 to M-1 generate
        n_loop: for j in 0 to N-1 generate
            mult_inst : mult
            port map (
                a    => a(j),
                b    => b(i),
                pin  => pin(i)(j),
                cin  => cin(i)(j),
                pout => pout(i)(j),
                cout => cout(i)(j) );
        end generate;
    end generate;

    cin_init: for j in 0 to N-1 generate 
        cin(0)(j) <= '0'; 
    end generate;

    cin_mloop: for i in 1 to M-1 generate
        cin_nloop: for j in 0 to N-2 generate 
            cin(i)(j) <= pout(i-1)(j+1); 
        end generate;
        cin(i)(N-1) <= cout(i-1)(N-1);
    end generate;

    pin_mloop: for i in 0 to M-1 generate 
        pin(i)(0) <= '0'; 
        pin_nloop: for j in 1 to N-1 generate 
            pin(i)(j) <= cout(i)(j-1); 
        end generate;
    end generate;

    prod_loop: for j in 0 to M-1 generate
        prod(j) <= pout(j)(0);
    end generate;

    prod(M+N-2 downto M) <= pout(M-1)(N-1 downto 1);
    prod(M+N-1) <= cout(M-1)(N-1);

end behavioral;
```

**simulation**

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity NM_mult_tb is
end NM_mult_tb;

architecture behavioral of NM_mult_tb is

component generic_mult
generic (M: integer := 4; N: integer := 4);
    port (
        a    :  in  std_logic_vector(M-1 downto 0);
        b    :  in  std_logic_vector(N-1 downto 0);
        prod :  out std_logic_vector(M+N-1 downto 0) );
end component;

-- signals
signal a       : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) :="0101";
signal b       : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) :="1010";
signal answer  : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal correct : std_logic;

begin
    -- Instantiating the Design Under Test (DUT)
    dut: generic_mult
    generic map (
        M => 4,
        N => 4 )
    port map (
        a    => a,
        b    => b,
        prod => answer );

    -- Stimulus process
    stim_proc: process
    begin
        wait for 1 ns;
        a <= a + 1;
        if a = "0" then
            b <= b + 1;
        end if;
    end process;

    -- Check results
    correct <= '1' when to_integer(unsigned(a))*to_integer(unsigned(b)) = 
    to_integer(unsigned(answer)) else '0';

end behavioral;
```

[image: Simulation]

The first thing I did was to simplify the `mult` entity. And since it is implemented as a 1-bit multiplier, I changed the signal names.

For `generic_mult`, I found it much easier to split your `carry_internal` and `sum_internal` buses to separate in/out buses. It removed a lot of the confusion. From there, it's not too difficult - as I think you'll see from the code.

Lastly, I changed your

> generic (bits: integer);

to

> generic (N: integer; M: integer);

to allow for MxN widths.